# Disable buttons when clicked in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have several buttons in a page of an AngularJS app. When a button is clicked, an array is populated and I need to disable that button. I can populate the array and display it in the page every time a button is clicked but not sure how I should disable the clicked buttons (may be write a directive, not sure). Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Here is my code:

Page:

```
<div>
  <button ng-click="click(1)">1</button>
  <button ng-click="click(2)">2</button>
  <button ng-click="click(3)">3</button>
  <button ng-click="click(4)">4</button>
  <button ng-click="click(5)">5</button>
</div>
<label>Selected Seats</label>
<div class="row">
  <ul ng-repeat="r in reserved">
      {{r}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.reserved =[];
$scope.click = function(value){
  $scope.reserved.push(value);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a helper function:

```
$scope.isReserved = function(value) {
    return $scope.reserved.indexOf(value) > -1;
};
```

and use it like this:

```
<button ng-click="click(1)" ng-disabled="isReserved(1)">1</button>
<button ng-click="click(2)" ng-disabled="isReserved(2)">2</button>
<button ng-click="click(3)" ng-disabled="isReserved(3)">3</button>
<button ng-click="click(4)" ng-disabled="isReserved(4)">4</button>
<button ng-click="click(5)" ng-disabled="isReserved(5)">5</button>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/OeWnZTWHSK2DUhyOPbK0?p=preview